# Check Mark Showing as a Black Box in Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drop-down-menu, menuitem

I have a menu inside a toolbar that needs to be checkable but when I check the items it renders as just a black box (I tried to upload a photo of the issue but StackOverflow wouldn't let me). When you mouse over the check mark renders correctly. I don't understand it I have tried removing any styles that might be affecting it but nothing seems to affect it.

Can anyone help?

Here is the XAML for the menu item:

```
<ToolBar ToolBarTray.IsLocked="True" Margin="0" Padding="0" ToolBar.OverflowMode="Never">
    <Button Command="com:FormatCommands.LogInCommand">
        <Viewbox Width="15">
            <Image Source="..\Resources\Login.png"/>
        </Viewbox>                        
    </Button>
    <Button Command="com:FormatCommands.LogOutCommand">
        <Viewbox Width="15">
            <Image Source="..\Resources\Logout.png"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
    <Button Command="com:FormatCommands.GetTodaysRacesCommand">
        <Viewbox Width="15">
            <Image Source="..\Resources\list.png"/>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Markets">
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="British"/>
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Irish" />
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>            
</ToolBar>
```

Comment: There is nothing in your example code given here that would give a hint about why you experience a problem with the checkmark rendering. Perhaps upload your screenshot to some image hoster like imgur.com (or any of the other free image upload sites) and put a link to that image in your question. My unsubstantiated blind guess is that you have a theme and/or a custom controltemplate for the MenuItem data type installed which causes the problems. What Windows version are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ToolBar` element defines some styles for a few controls and the `Menu` is one of them. You can find the `Style` key defined in the `ToolBar.MenuStyleKey` static property. That style is setting the `Background` to `#FF212121` for the Panel which contains the check mark.

Unfortunately i don't believe that there is a way to change only the background for the check mark's panel, you will have to override that ugly looking `MenuItem` style.

**Note**: to get the style applied in your case follow this steps:

1. Copy the above XAML in a new VS solution.
2. Select the `Menu` in the designer window.
3. Right click on the `Menu`/ Edit Template / Edit a copy / Enter.

Comment: Thank you I had no idea you could access the styles like that. So when I find the part that is causing me issues do I need to copy the whole style back into my previous project?

Comment: Yes you should copy all the styles generated with the above method and modify only the parts that you need, it's a good practice for overriding Templates for any control.

Comment: You're a genius thank you! You have just saved me so many hours.