# Blackbox checkmark in checked menu item

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

I'm having a weird problem with `MenuItem` objects that have `IsCheckable=True` - a screenshot is worth a thousand words:

[image: Blackbox checkmark in checked menu item]

This looks very much like *[Check Mark Showing as a Black Box in Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643480/1188513)*, except the accepted answer there, unless I misread it badly, suggests to tweak `ToolBar.MenuStyleKey`, which doesn't seem to be tweaking the right thing at all:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static ToolBar.MenuStyleKey}" TargetType="Menu">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
</Style>
```

[image: Yay, a yellow menu... still blackbox checked menuitem]

So, how do I get to that black box, and make it, say, `GhostWhite`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me.

[image]

Exported the template per the instructions in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20643480/1188513) you referenced.

Applied that style to the `MneuItems`.

```
<ToolBar>
    <Button Content="One"/>
    <Button Content="Two"/>
    <Menu>
        <MenuItem Header="Markets" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}">
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="British" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}"/>
            <MenuItem IsCheckable="True" Header="Irish" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
</ToolBar>
```

Changed `Background` to `Yellow` in the template as such:

```
<Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#80DADADA" BorderThickness="1" Background="Yellow" Height="20" Margin="0,1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="20">
```

Just to make this example totally complete, below is the template that I exported:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,3"/>
        <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="1,0"/>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#80DADADA" BorderThickness="1" Background="Yellow" Height="20" Margin="0,1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="20">
                            <Path Data="M0,2.5L2.5,5 7,0.5" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1.2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="4,3,2,3" Text="{TemplateBinding InputGestureText}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#80DADADA"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#210080FF"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#90006CD9"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FFEEF5FD"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,2,7,2"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <DockPanel x:Name="Header">
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="M0,2.5L2.5,5 7,0.5" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="4,0,6,0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1.2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" HorizontalOffset="-1" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom">
                                        <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                                            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FFB6BDC5" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFEEF5FD">
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFEEF5FD" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="1" Margin="0,-1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Header}"/>
                                                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                                        <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                                <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                                            </Canvas>
                                                            <Rectangle Fill="#FFEEF5FD" Margin="0,1"/>
                                                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Margin="0,0,0,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </ScrollViewer>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                                    </Popup>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#80DADADA"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#210080FF"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSubmenuOpen" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#FFB6BDC5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#FFEEF5FD"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" TargetName="Shdw" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="7,1,8,2"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <DockPanel>
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="4,0,6,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="M0,2.5L2.5,5 7,0.5" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="4,0,6,0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1.2" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                </DockPanel>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#80DADADA"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#210080FF"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="SubmenuHeader">
                <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" Value="Top"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8,3"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Grid Background="Transparent" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIGTColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Margin="1,0"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding Icon}" ContentSource="Icon" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#80DADADA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF212121" Height="20" Margin="0,1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="20">
                                    <Path Data="M0,2.5L2.5,5 7,0.5" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" StrokeThickness="1.2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Border>
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                <Path Grid.Column="3" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Data="M0,0L4,3.5 0,7z" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Margin="4,0,6,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Right">
                                    <Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome x:Name="Shdw" Color="Transparent">
                                        <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="#FFB6BDC5" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FFEEF5FD" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
                                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                                <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="24" SharedSizeGroup="MenuItemIconColumnGroup" Width="Auto"/>
                                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                                        <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                                    </Canvas>
                                                    <Rectangle Fill="#FFEEF5FD" Margin="0,1"/>
                                                    <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Margin="0,0,0,1" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </ScrollViewer>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Themes:SystemDropShadowChrome>
                                </Popup>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Border" Value="#80DADADA"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="#210080FF"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#90006CD9"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="#FFEEF5FD"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="HasDropShadow" SourceName="PART_Popup" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Margin" TargetName="Shdw" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" TargetName="Shdw" Value="True"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Color" TargetName="Shdw" Value="#71000000"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Awesome, I *did* misread it then! Thanks! If you're interested, I have the actual control's markup up for review [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/120124/23788)

Comment: This helped me :) However it is ridiculous that this much work is required to be able to change a checkmark style from the broken black background ...