# WPF Menu Item check mark is blacked in Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf

I created a small menu bar with some checked menu items. It is blacked out in Windows 10 but displayed fine in Windows 7

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="CheckMenuTickinWin10.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CheckMenuTickinWin10"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <ToolBar>
            <Menu>
                <MenuItem Header="menu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Sub" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Sub" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Sub" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True"/>
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </ToolBar>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image]

What should I do in Windows 10 to make the check mark visible?

Comment: Have you read this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643480/check-mark-showing-as-a-black-box-in-menu

Comment: @SebastianSchulz Thanks, done that and working now. Pls post the same as answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This background is defined in the default [ControlTemplate](https://wpftutorial.net/Templates.html) of the menu item. A template defines the look of a control, if you don't define a template for the control, it will pick up the default template.

The good news is that you are free to edit the `ControlTemplate` to customize the control as whatever you like. The not so good news is that you have to be comfortable with a bunch of XAML code (hundreds of lines for a single template).

**First find the "default" ControlTemplate of the MenuItem in Visual Studio.**

In the VS designer, right click the SubMenuItem, and choose "Edit Template" -> "Edit a Copy" from the dropdown menu. This will automatically copy the default template of the SubMenuItem to a style name "MenuItemStyle1" as defined in the window's Resource dictionary.

**Remove the black background from the template.**

Expand `MenuItemStyle1`, find the following line that defines the black border.

```
<Border x:Name="GlyphPanel" BorderBrush="#80DADADA" BorderThickness="1" Background="#FF212121" Height="20" Margin="0,1" Visibility="Hidden" Width="20">
```

Change the Background color from "#FF212121" to "#FFEEF5FD", and save the change. (#FFEEF5FD is the hightlight color of the border, it is also the color of the light background of the menu, you can find this color in the default template.)

**Then apply this new template to all 3 menu items.**

```
<MenuItem Header="menu">
    <MenuItem Header="Sub" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Sub" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="False" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}" />
    <MenuItem Header="Sub" IsCheckable="True" IsChecked="True" Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}" />
</MenuItem>
```

[image: menu to edit template]